# Issues installing Mendeley

Tags: mendeley

The refered [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x30yUI3g8oY&feature=emb_logo).
The commands used in order:

1)`wget https://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt/pool/main/m/mendeleydesktop/mendeleydesktop_1.19.4-stable_amd64.deb`

2)`sudo dpkg -i /mendeleydesktop_1.19.4-stable_amd64.deb`

3`sudo apt -f install`

It fails as soon as I input my password as required in the second step. This is what the terminal shows me:

```
dpkg: error: cannot access archive '/mendeleydesktop_1.19.4-stable_amd64.deb': No such file or directory
```

Also, in the Mendeley website the current versions of the software seem to be incompatible with 20.4.

Comment: Your first command will download (`wget`) the file and save it in your $PWD (present working directory; ie. relative), then your second command tells it to install it from the defined path (in the root directory, not relative/$PWD) so your second command doesn't match your first UNLESS you were in '/' to begin with, where I'd expect the first command to fail as `sudo` wasn't used.  Your commands imply you didn't understand them, as they contradict (at least as provided).  If you didn't get an error as the first command, you're second needs to reflect the $PWD/save location of the first command

Comment: I think it's more likely that the first command fails, since the ending of this command is indeed: `/mendeleydesktop_1.19.4-stable_amd64.deb` (starting with /, thus saving in root). Try using sudo for the first command also.